# Converting bytes to Int64s/Floats/Doubles in Haskell

Tags: haskell, bit

I'm trying to parse a binary file format in Haskell (Apple's binary property list format), and one of the things required by the format is to treat sequences of bytes as either (a) unsigned 1-, 2-, or 4-byte integers; (b) signed 8-byte integers; (c) 32-bit `float`s; and (d) 64-bit `double`s.  Converting sequences of bytes to unsigned integers is easy, and even dealing with signed integers wouldn't be *terrible*.  But for signed integers, and *especially* for `Float`s and `Double`s, I don't really want to implement the logic myself.  I've been able to find functions `int2Float# :: Int# -> Float#` and `int2Double# :: Int# -> Double#` in [GHC.Prim](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.2.0.0/GHC-Prim.html), but these don't seem ideal (I don't particularly want to be working with unboxed types).  My hope is that there's some way to cast from either a `[Word8]` or `Word32`s/`Word64`s.  Are there any functions of type `Word32 -> Float`, `Word64 -> Double`, `Word64 -> Int64`, or similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you aren't aware, `fromIntegral` converts integrals perfectly well.  Also, the [binary](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.5.0.2) package and associated [data-binary-ieee754](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-binary-ieee754) package are very applicable to your problem.

```hs
λ> :set -XOverloadedStrings
λ> import           Data.Binary.Get       (runGet)
λ> import qualified Data.Binary.IEEE754   as I
λ> runGet I.getFloat32le "\STX\SOH\SOH\SOH"
2.369428e-38
λ> runGet I.getFloat32le "\STX\SOH\SOH\SOHtrailing characters are ignored"
2.369428e-38
λ> runGet I.getFloat32le "\STX\SOH\SOH" -- remember to use `catch`:
*** Exception: Data.Binary.Get.runGet at position 0: not enough bytes
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries/binary/src/Data/Binary/Get.hs:351:5 in binary-0.8.5.1:Data.Binary.Get
```

Comment: Looks like `Data.Binary.IEEE754` effectively does `unsafePerformIO $ peek . castPtr . poke`, which is about as safe as `unsafeCoerce`.  Still useful, though – it means that `-0` and `NaN` actually round-trip correctly.

Comment: And it doesn't require beginners to know about / directly use `unsafeCoerce`.

Comment: I didn't realize `fromIntegral` would work with the fixed-width types—I should have tested that.

Comment: Inspired by [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976684/converting-ieee-754-floating-point-in-haskell-word32-64-to-and-from-haskell-floa), I have released a package on Hackage that implements reinterpretation casts, and tries to stay updated with the fastest implementation known: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reinterpret-cast

Answer (score 1):

[`Unsafe.Coerce.unsafeCoerce`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/libraries/base-4.3.0.0/Unsafe-Coerce.html) can convert between types, like C++'s `reinterpret_cast<>`.  Use with caution.

Otherwise, you can implement your own [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) decoding using [`RealFloat`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0-latest/html/libraries/base-4.3.0.0/Prelude.html#t%3aRealFloat).

```
bitsAsIEEE754 :: (Bits a, Integral a, RealFloat b) => a -> b
bitsAsIEEE754 word =
    assert (floatRadix float == 2) $
    assert (bitSize word == 1 + es + ms) $
    assert (1 `shiftL` es == maxE - minE + 3) $
    float
  where
    ms = floatDigits float - 1
    (minE, maxE) = floatRange float
    es = length $ takeWhile (< maxE - minE + 2) $ iterate (* 2) 1
    sgn = if testBit word (ms + es) then negate else id
    e = fromIntegral $ word `shiftR` ms .&. (1 `shiftL` es - 1)
    nor = if e == 0 then id else flip setBit ms
    m = sgn . toInteger . nor $ word .&. (1 `shiftL` ms - 1)
    float = encodeFloat m $ max minE (e + minE - 1) - ms - 1
```

At least with my GHC, it doesn't seem possible to create `-0` and `NaN` using `encodeFloat`, but everything else should work.

Comment: `unsafeCoerce` is not correct for floating <-> integral conversion, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976684/converting-ieee-754-floating-point-in-haskell-word32-64-to-and-from-haskell-floa) and [here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2209).